# Did not find the answer to specific requirement

Tags: excel

I have the data in below format:

```
A -100
B -234
C -32

A -123
B -221
D -456

A -145
B -245
C -312
D -478
```

I want to format this data as:

```
A     B      C     D

100   234     32   
123   221         456
145   245    312  478
```

Could you please help me how I can achieve this in excel?

Kind Regards,
Neeraj Sharma

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [It appears no attempt has been made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: If you could work out a way of numbering each group, you could just use a pivot table to get it into the required format.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Copy and paste data into a different sheet, when you copy paste select paste as transpose
- Step 2: Then select the data and go to DATA->text to columns and give delimiter as -
- Step 3: Then again copy paste with transpose

Comment: Hi, Transpose option does not work for my requirement  as I have large amount of data in excel.